# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement underTimelyRenewal

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis

I am getting the below exception before hitting a axis 2 webservice.

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement underTimelyRenewal

I can't reproduce the same issue locally on tomcat or in DEV environment which runs in Weblogic. It justs happens only in 1 environment which runs on Weblogic 11g. This makes to think that I am missing some config in that environment, I am not sure what it is. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Here is code that calls web service.

```
public  com.ibs.accouting.employeeVerificationResponse getEmployeeVerificationRequest(

                        com.ibs.accounting.EmployeeVerificationRequest employeeVerificationRequest108)


                throws java.rmi.RemoteException

                {
          org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext _messageContext = null;
          try{
           org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient _operationClient = _serviceClient.createClient(_operations[5].getName());
          _operationClient.getOptions().setAction("http://ibs.com/accounting/WBLEmployeeVerificationRequest");
          _operationClient.getOptions().setExceptionToBeThrownOnSOAPFault(true);



              addPropertyToOperationClient(_operationClient,org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL2Constants.ATTR_WHTTP_QUERY_PARAMETER_SEPARATOR,"&");


          // create a message context
          _messageContext = new org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext();



          // create SOAP envelope with that payload
          org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope env = null;


                                                env = toEnvelope(getFactory(_operationClient.getOptions().getSoapVersionURI()),
                                                employeeVerificationRequest108,
                                                optimizeContent(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://ibs.com/accounting",
                                                "getEmployeeVerificationRequest")));

    //adding SOAP soap_headers
     _serviceClient.addHeadersToEnvelope(env);
    // set the message context with that soap envelope
    _messageContext.setEnvelope(env);

    // add the message contxt to the operation client
    _operationClient.addMessageContext(_messageContext);

    //execute the operation client
    _operationClient.execute(true);


           org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext _returnMessageContext = _operationClient.getMessageContext(
                                       org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDLConstants.MESSAGE_LABEL_IN_VALUE);
            org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope _returnEnv = _returnMessageContext.getEnvelope();


                            java.lang.Object object = fromOM(
                                         _returnEnv.getBody().getFirstElement() ,
                                         com.ibs.accounting.EmployeeVerificationResponse.class,
                                          getEnvelopeNamespaces(_returnEnv));


                                    return (com.ibs.accounting.EmployeeVerificationResponse)object;

     }catch(org.apache.axis2.AxisFault f){

        org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement faultElt = f.getDetail();
        if (faultElt!=null){
            if (faultExceptionNameMap.containsKey(faultElt.getQName())){
                //make the fault by reflection
                try{
                    java.lang.String exceptionClassName = (java.lang.String)faultExceptionClassNameMap.get(faultElt.getQName());
                    java.lang.Class exceptionClass = java.lang.Class.forName(exceptionClassName);
                    java.lang.Exception ex=
                            (java.lang.Exception) exceptionClass.newInstance();
                    //message class
                    java.lang.String messageClassName = (java.lang.String)faultMessageMap.get(faultElt.getQName());
                    java.lang.Class messageClass = java.lang.Class.forName(messageClassName);
                    java.lang.Object messageObject = fromOM(faultElt,messageClass,null);
                    java.lang.reflect.Method m = exceptionClass.getMethod("setFaultMessage",
                               new java.lang.Class[]{messageClass});
                    m.invoke(ex,new java.lang.Object[]{messageObject});


                    throw new java.rmi.RemoteException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
                }catch(java.lang.ClassCastException e){
                   // we cannot intantiate the class - throw the original Axis fault
                    throw f;
                } catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // we cannot intantiate the class - throw the original Axis fault
                    throw f;
                }catch (java.lang.NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    // we cannot intantiate the class - throw the original Axis fault
                    throw f;
                } catch (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException e) {
                    // we cannot intantiate the class - throw the original Axis fault
                    throw f;
                }  catch (java.lang.IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // we cannot intantiate the class - throw the original Axis fault
                    throw f;
                }   catch (java.lang.InstantiationException e) {
                    // we cannot intantiate the class - throw the original Axis fault
                    throw f;
                }
            }else{
                throw f;
            }
        }else{
            throw f;
        }
        } finally {
            _messageContext.getTransportOut().getSender().cleanup(_messageContext);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a common exception when using Axis. It usually means that the client & server WSDL/XSD are out of sync.

Comment: Thanks for responding Reimeus. What's puzzling is the same client (ear project) and server (aar) when deployed to local and other environment works fine. How do I sync WSDL/XSD on server side? Is it done in aar or some where in axis2 deployed on the app server?

Comment: This may be because of java version. If web service is deployed in java5 and client is in java6,this error may come. Please check on this aspect also

Answer (score 0):

This error can be kind of misleading. AFter I modified the WSDL and added a new mandatory element, I created my client. Than this error appeared. The solution was, that I forgot to fill this element in one method of the my web service. If this error appears, also check if your mandatory elements are filled within the server.
That it works under one environment and not in an other can also mean, that a mandatory item is filled on one server (development server) and not under the other (productive server).